# Link without trailing slash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I use the following in MVC to create a link to my home page in my application:

```
<a href="~/">home</a>
```

Unfortunately, when this is run under an app, this will create a link like

```
<a href="/app-name/">home</a>
```

Is there a way to create this link to the `app-name` without the trailing slash (or without just hardcoding the it)?

Our site is canonicalised so that any urls with a trailing slash end up being redirected to their non trailing slash version and because this link has a trailing slash on, it is causing unnecessary redirect hops, which is penalising our seo ratings

Comment: I suggest checking whether the URL EndsWith("/") and if so, gather the Substring(0, MyString.Length - 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Lajos Arpad, it got me of thinking into another of making up the url so I thought if I use the `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute` I may be able to then substring the result.

But using the following meant I didn't need to substring to get the url I needed:

```
<a href="@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~")">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Html.ActionLink helper should generate a link that conforms to your requirements:

```
@Html.ActionLink("home", "Index", "Home")
```

Assuming your homepage is called "Index" and rendered by the "HomeController".

Comment: Unfortunately this also adds the trailing slash

Comment: Looks like the routing in your app is configured differently from my app. Is [RouteCollection.AppendTrailingSlash](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.appendtrailingslash(v=vs.110).aspx) set to true?

Comment: Not sure - I haven't set it so unless the default is for it to be true then I don't think so

Comment: Default is false. If is set `RouteTable.Routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;` I also see the URL from my example with a trailing slash. If I do not add this line, I see no trailing slash.

Comment: Hmmm, very strange.  I've not added it to my route config so not sure why mine is appending the trailing slash

Comment: @Pete, may be it is related to something like environment defaults. If I were you, I would try adding `RouteTable.Routes.AppendTrailingSlash = false;` and testing manually instead of using `<a href="@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~")">Home</a>`

Comment: @AdilMammadov to be fair I have used an actual link instead of an actionlink because I have a lot of schema data on the link and meta / schema data inside the link - It's my main home link  so I use it for my schema orginasation data